# Unable to pass a proper lambda to emscripten_set_main_loop

Tags: c++, lambda, callback, emscripten

I'm really struggling to instruct [emscripten_set_main_loop](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/emscripten.h.html#c.emscripten_set_main_loop) to execute a method that renders a new frame. I'm simply unable to come up with a lambda that successfully compiles, let alone runs as expected.

First, I got the `MyView`class that should serve as the interface to Javascript. The idea is to create a new object of that type and then invoke `StartRenderingLoop`which would start the loop that renders new frames. This should be done from Javascript which is why I got the [Embind](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html) definition at the bottom:

```
class MyView
{
public:
  void StartRenderingLoop();

private:
  std::unique_ptr<Renderer> _renderer;
  void Render();
};

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
MyView::MyView()
{
  _renderer = std::unique_ptr<Renderer>(new Renderer());
}

void MyView::Render()
{
  _renderer->Render();
}

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
void MyView::StartRenderingLoop()
{
  emscripten_set_main_loop(/* should invoke MyView::Render(), but how? */, -1, 1);
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(MyView)
{
  class_<MyView>("MyView")
    .function("startRenderingLoop", &MyView::StartRenderingLoop)
    // everything else...
    ;
}
```

Here's what I tried:

1. This won't even compile:

   ```
   emscripten_set_main_loop(&MyView::Render(), -1, 1);
   ```

   Emscripten throws the following error:

   ```
   note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'void (MyView::*)()' to 'em_callback_func' (aka 'void (*)()') for 1st argument
   ```
2. Does not compile:

   ```
   emscripten_set_main_loop([]() { _renderer->Render(); }, -1, 1);
   ```

   Because it cannot access the `this` pointer, fair enough:

   ```
   error: 'this' cannot be implicitly captured in this context
   ```
3. Capturing `this` makes the lambda incompatible with whatever is expected and throws an error similar to attempt 1):

   ```
   emscripten_set_main_loop([this]() { _renderer->Render(); }, -1, 1);
   ```
4. Declare a global `std::function` object:

   ```
   static std::function<void()> renderLoopFunction;
   ```

   then in `StartRenderingLoop` do something like this:

   ```
   EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
   void MyView::StartRenderingLoop()
   {
     renderLoopFunction = [=]() mutable { int test = 3; };
     emscripten_set_main_loop(renderLoopFunction, -1, 1);
   }
   ```

   Contrary to resources such as [this](http://sasq64.github.io/cpp-closures.html) it again fails to compile:

   ```
   note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::function<void ()>' to 'em_callback_func' (aka 'void (*)()') for 1st argument
   ```

I'm at the stage where, if a fairy with three free wishes would show up, I'd gladly invest one of these into solving that mystery just to have the compiler stop telling me what an incompetent idiot I am.

Comment: you need to pass the address of a plain old function. Not a function object or member function pointer.

Comment: I tried this as well, but didn't list it. The problem there what to put into that plain old function. Since it has no relation to my class I'd need to instantiate a new object within it just to be able to call `MyView::Render()`. However, that is supposed to be done from Javascript

Comment: Then I think you should give up using classes and Embind and should use plain old functions to communicate with JS. Just adding EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE macro to a plain function will make it callable in JS side without additional configurations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that in order to utilize `emscripten_set_main_loop_arg` I'd really have to fall back to using C. Because I prefer to keep the code object oriented as far as possible, I was looking for an alternative. As it turns out, there is a second version of that function that is able to process an argument: `emscripten_set_main_loop_arg`.

Using `emscripten_set_main_loop_arg` I can keep `StartRenderingLoop` method as an instance method and just pass `this` to the `Render` callback. The modified code looks as follows:

```
void MyView::Render()
{
  _renderer->Render();
}


void RenderLoopCallback(void* arg)
{
  static_cast<MyView*>(arg)->Render();
}


EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
void MyView::StartRenderingLoop()
{
  emscripten_set_main_loop_arg(&RenderLoopCallback, this, -1, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The interface requires a plain old c function pointer of type `void (*)()`.

Assuming you only intend to have one `Render` object...

```
class MyView
{
public:
  void Render();

private:
  std::unique_ptr<Renderer> _renderer;
};

// a global or otherwise known globally
auto view = MyView();

// &main_loop has the signature void (*)(), which is what you need
void main_loop()
{
  view.Render();
}

int main()
{
   emscripten_set_main_loop(&main_loop, -1, 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer motivated me to further investigate whether I could keep the code object oriented as it was. Turns out there is an additional method that allows me this. I've posted how I solved it, and will accepted it as answer once I can. Upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have been doing:

```cpp
   void do_frame(void* void_fn_ptr) {
        auto* fn_ptr = reinterpret_cast<std::function<void()>*>(void_fn_ptr);
        if (fn_ptr) {
            auto& fn = *fn_ptr;
            fn();
        }
    }


    void window::loop(std::function<void()> fn) {
        #ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
            emscripten_set_main_loop_arg(do_frame, &fn, 0, 1);
        #else
            while (!should_close()) {
                fn();
            }
        #endif
    }
```

And then:

```cpp
    w.loop([&]() {
        // render stuff...
    });
```